# cassandra - The same query work with cql but not with python driver

Tags: python, cassandra, cql, cql3

I have a strange problem here. I have a cassandra table called `events_prime` and I want to request the DB to get elements from this table with a WHERE clause.

I am using the python `cassandra-driver` and this is my request:

```py
prep_stment = session.prepare("""
    SELECT * FROM events_prime WHERE "websiteId" = '%s-%s' AND churner=True AND "currentTime" > '%s' AND "currentTime" < '%s' LIMIT 20000;
    """%(platform,client,time_2,time_1))
    print prep_stment
    print "Request DB..."
    frames = []
    for res in session.execute(prep_stment):
        frames.append(pd.DataFrame(res))
    df = pd.concat(frames)
    print df.shape
```

The output:

```py
Out[1]: Request cassandra...
Out[2]: <PreparedStatement query="
    SELECT * FROM events_prime WHERE "websiteId" = 'sd-8231' AND churner=True AND "currentTime" > '2016-03-08 21:32:14' AND "currentTime" < '2016-03-08 23:32:14' LIMIT 20000;
    ", consistency=Not Set>
Out[3]: Request DB...

Out[4]: (0, 31)
```

That means that there is no data with the given constraints!

**BUT** when I run `SELECT * FROM events_prime WHERE "websiteId" = 'sd-8231' AND churner=True AND "currentTime" > '2016-03-08 21:32:14' AND "currentTime" < '2016-03-08 23:32:14' LIMIT 20000;` (which is the same query in python driver ) directly in cql I get 100 rows?

Any explanation? Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried just printing out the results from the python driver instead of adding them to the dataframe? To check whether or not you are actually getting things through the python driver.

Comment: maybe your "session" is not properly instantiated, check it out

Comment: Could you show us more of your Python code, _i.e._ how `session` is created/set up?